# How to setState of an array of objects in functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-state, react-state-management

I am trying to setState of an Array of objects when component load.
state of the component is:

```
   const [weekdays, setWeekdays] = useState([{
    day: 'S',
    fullName: 'Sunday',
    select: false
},
{
    day: 'M',
    fullName: 'Monday',
    select: false
},
{
    day: 'T',
    fullName: 'Tuesday',
    select: false
},
{
    day: 'W',
    fullName: 'Wednesday',
    select: false
},
{
    day: 'T',
    fullName: 'Thursday',
    select: false
},
{
    day: 'F',
    fullName: 'Friday',
    select: false
},
{
    day: 'S',
    fullName: 'Saturday',
    select: false
}])
```

The array which I am trying to setState is: [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeUMI.png)

I am trying in this way to setState when page loads:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    {
        (data?.length > 0)
            ?
            setWeekdays([weekdays => (
                {
                    ...weekdays,
                    ...data?.map((item) => { return { day: item.day, fullName:item.fullName, select:true } }),
                })])
            :
            setWeekdays([...weekdays])
    }
}, [data]);
```

Thanks...

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You have a `weekdays` array and each item in  it have a `selected` field, then you get some `data` array which includes some of the weekdays and what you want to do is update the selected field to true for the days that are included in that data array. Is this your question?

Comment: yes,exactly that is my question I want to update the selected fields

Comment: Why don't you do what @Trevin Avery
said in the answer? Saving it as an object with key value pairs of : `{ sunday: {...} , moday: {...}}` instead of an array will make it much easier to update.

Comment: Yes,I have tried but it gives TypeError: weekdays.map is not a function

Comment: Posted my answer to this. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### These are two ways of solving this.

**First one:**

- Following the approach for the `weekdays` and `data` structure you have in your
  question code - with each one as an array of objects:

  ```
     useEffect(() => {
         const newWeekdays = [];
         if (data?.length > 0) {
           setWeekdays((weekdays) => {
             for (const item in data) {
               if (data[item] !== "") {
                 newWeekdays.push({ ...weekdays[item], select: true });
               } else {
                 newWeekdays.push({ ...weekdays[item] });
               }
             }
             return newWeekdays;
           });
         }
       }, [data]);
  ```

**Second one:** (which I think is better)

- You can have the `data` as a simple array of `indexes`. This array
  will contain the indexes to the days objects that should be selected
  in the `weekdays` array. (You can leave the `weekdays` structure as
  it is in your question.)

  So now this how the data array looks like:

  ```
  const data = [0, 2, 4]; //Sunday, Tuesday, Thursday
  ```

  And this is how you can update the selected indexes to `select:true`
  :

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
      if (data?.length > 0) {
        setWeekdays((weekdays) => {
          const newWeekdays = weekdays.map((item, index) => {
            if (data.includes(index)) {
              return { ...item, select: true };
            }
            return { ...item };
          });
          return newWeekdays;
        });
      }
    }, [data]);
  ```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: This helped me.first one works perfectly without doing any changes....Thanks a lot for sharing your solution   @Tehila

Comment: Happy it helped! Though I think the second one will be much easier to work with... But do as you like :)

Answer (score 0):

You created `weekdays` as an array, but when you call `setWeekdays` you are returning an object. You need to make sure your new value is the same structure.

That said, your current data structure is not very efficient. If I understand correctly, you simply want to store which set of days are selected. You would do better to have an object instead of an array.

```
const [weekdays, setWeekdays] = useState({
  sunday: {
    day: 'S',
    fullName: 'Sunday',
    select: false
  },
  monday: {
    day: 'M',
    fullName: 'Monday',
    select: false
  },
  tuesday: {
    day: 'T',
    fullName: 'Tuesday',
    select: false
  },
  wednesday: {
    day: 'W',
    fullName: 'Wednesday',
    select: false
  },
  thursday: {
    day: 'T',
    fullName: 'Thursday',
    select: false
  },
  friday: {
    day: 'F',
    fullName: 'Friday',
    select: false
  },
  saturday: {
    day: 'S',
    fullName: 'Saturday',
    select: false
  }
})
```

```
const data = ['monday', 'wednesday', 'friday']
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  setWeekdays(weekdays => ({
    ...weekdays,
    ...data
      .map(key => ({[key]: {...weekdays[key], selected: true}}))
      .reduce((prev, next) => Object.assign(prev, next))
  })
}, [data]);
```

Comment: It gives TypeError: weekdays.map is not a function

Comment: I don't think you copied it correctly. The example doesn't call `weekdays.map`, so that error must be happening somewhere else.